# Ошибка "NameError: name 'k' is not defined."

Tags: python

Выдаёт ошибку

> NameError: name 'k' is not defined.

```py
def skrabl():
    slovo = input("Введите слово (русскими маленькими буквами)")
    global k
    k == 0
    for i in slovo:
        if i in "авеинорст":
            k += 1
        if i in "дклмпу":
            k += 2
        if i in "бгёья":
            k += 3
        if i in "ый":
            k += 4
        if i in "жзчцх":
            k += 5
        if i in "эшю":
            k += 8
        if i in "ъщф":
            k += 10
    print(k)
    if k > 15:
        print("ОЛЕЕЕЕ-ОЛЕ-ОЛЕ-ОЛЕ! ТЫ ВЫИГРАЛ!")

skrabl()
```

помогите.

Comment: `k == 0` => `k = 0`

Comment: У Вас  `k == 0` а должно быть  `k = 0`

Comment: Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) проблемы до публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!

Дело в том, что вы используете оператор сравнения (`==`) вместо присваивания (`=`)

Также, в вашем коде могут возникнуть ошибки, связанные с отступами (`IndentationError`). Вот исправленный код:

```py
def skrabl():
    global k
    k = 0
    
    slovo = input("Введите слово (русскими маленькими буквами)")
    for i in slovo:
        if i in "авеинорст":
            k += 1
        if i in "дклмпу":
            k += 2
        if i in "бгёья":
            k += 3
        if i in "ый":
            k += 4
        if i in "жзчцх":
            k += 5
        if i in "эшю":
            k += 8
        if i in "ъщф":
            k += 10
print(k)
if k > 15:
    print("ОЛЕЕЕЕ-ОЛЕ-ОЛЕ-ОЛЕ! ТЫ ВЫИГРАЛ!")
```